# After cloning a VM with virt-clone, how do I rename the newly created qcow2 file?

Tags: virtual-machine, libvirt, clone, qcow2

I wanted to build another server based on an existing config, so I performed the following:

```
[user@box ~]# virt-clone --original serverA-rhel8 --name serverB-rhel8 --auto-clone
Allocating 'serverA-rhel8-1-clone.qcow2'      | 200 GB  00:00:16
```

As you can see, cloning resulted in a new qcow2 file, however the name of that file is misleading (since it is actually serverB-rhel8).

Is there a way to either configure the qcow2 name when issuing virt-clone, or renaming the new qcow2 file afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify `--file /path/to/new/file` and name it whatever you want